# Trouble registering custom fonts in mPDF 7

Tags: fonts, mpdf

I'm using mPDF 7.0.3. I try to register custom fonts that I have downloaded from Google Fonts (TTF format). I basically copied [the example from the documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html):

```php
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'fontDir' =>  array_merge($fontDirs, [
    __DIR__ . '/files/theme/fonts/Merriweather',
    __DIR__ . '/files/theme/fonts/Roboto',
  ]),

  'font_data' => $fontData + [
    "Merriweather" => [
        'L'  => 'Merriweather-Light.ttf',
        'R'  => 'Merriweather-Regular.ttf',
        'RI' => 'Merriweather-Italic.ttf',
        'B'  => 'Merriweather-Bold.ttf',
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
        'useKashida' => 75,
    ],
    "Roboto Mono" => [
      'L' => 'Roboto-Light.ttf',
      'R' => 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
      'M' => 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
      'useOTL' => 0xFF,
      'useKashida' => 75,
    ]
  ],
  'default_font' => 'Merriweather'
]);
```

My PDF is generated with fallback fonts though. I also implemented a Monolog logger following [this example](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/logging.html). It's output states that there are

> 5 fonts used {"context":"statistics"} []

There are no error messages even when I intentionally pass non-existing paths in `fontDir`. When I remove the `default_font` property the log counts only 4 fonts used.

Any ideas where this could come from or how I could further investigate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

As stated in [this part of the manual](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/font-names.html) mPDF expects font names to be lower case and without spaces. Declaring my fonts like this:

```
"merriweather" => [
   ...
],
"robotomono" => [
  ...
]
```

solved the problem.

In CSS I still refer to my fonts as *Merriweather* and *Roboto Mono*.